# VB .NET Nested For Loops with DrawRectangle = Lag and Vanish? (Read)

Tags: vb.net

I have been working on a project and to make sure everything is working, I created a piece of code that *Would* fill my form with pixels.

```
 For X As Integer = 0 To Me.Size.Width
        For Y As Integer = 0 To Me.Size.Height
            DrawPixel(Pens.BlueViolet, X, Y)
            Y += 1
        Next
        X += 1
    Next
```

Like a few pixels (*Very very few in the left corner*) get printed, then lag (wait cursor) ... then all the drawn pixels dissapear. Like it finished the drawing it's like "*Lag? Okay I'll just make it vanish :P*". I tried inserting a `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)`but it just makes the program lag even more.
Anyone have ideas on why it doesn't finish drawing, or how i could add a small timedelay without `thread.sleep` or `A Timer`?
Also DrawPixel is a subroutine of my own:

```
Friend Sub DrawPixel(clr As Pen, x As Integer, y As Integer)
    g.DrawRectangle(clr, New Rectangle(New Point(x, y), New Size(1, 1)))
End Sub
```

Ty

Comment: Drawing pixels one by one is so slow that Windows thinks your program keeled over.  So it puts up the ghost window with "Not responding" in the title bar.  Your code finally finishes, the ghost window disappears and your window repaints.  No more pixels.  Do pick up an introductory book on GUI programming, you don't have the right instincts.

Comment: @HansPassant  Okay aaand how do i make it not repaint?

Comment: where are you doing all this from? an event? which?...and where did `g` come from in DrawPixel?

Comment: `Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics()` at the top under the classname.

Comment: first, you **cant** make it not paint - thats windows job.  next, anytime something goes across the screen (mouse, another window) Windows will repaint that portion of the screen/window, so unless you are drawing in the Paint event, it **will** get undone.  you can change how you are doing things.  Of course FillRect will work.  Or you could draw to a bitmap and apply it to the form or whatever you are drawing on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paint in the paint event that will persist the drawing when the system repaints. Use the e.Graphics object not Me.CreateGraphics.

Comment: That worked, it didn't crash (*Well it took some time its a lot of pixels XD*) and it drew out everyhting i wanted! ... Thank you!